# Match text/html outside of PHP tags

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I'm searching for a solution, for this. It's easy to select all the content inside of PHP tags (basically ) but I cant seem to get the opposite to work.

First, I tought this would work:

```
/\?>(?<html>.*?)<\?|^(.*?)(?=<\?)|(?<=\? >)(.*?)$/
```

(everything between ?> and \<\?, everything between ^ and \<\?, everything between ?> and $)

But here, the problem is that a file that starts with `<?php`, and doesnt have a single other closing tag, until the end of the file, fails.

At the end of the day, I want to just match everything outside of `<? ... ?>`

```
THIS,<?php ... ?>
THIS<?php ... ?>
AND THIS
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: If it is easy to select all the content inside, why dont you just `preg_replace` those matches? This way you end up having a variable with just the contents outside the php tags.

Comment: Because I still need the rest to stay how it is, to use it for preg_replace_callback. I want to manipulate the content outside the php tags, and leave the code untouched, basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```php
$yourcode = <<<TXT
THIS
,
<?php 
... ?>
THIS

<?php 
... ?>
THIS TOO

<?php ... ?>AND 
THIS

TXT;

preg_match_all('/
    (?|
        ((?:(?!\?>).)+)(?:<\?php)          # all chars not containing "?>" sequence until "<?php"
        |                                  # or
        (?:\?>)((?:(?!\?>).)+)(?:<\?php)   # all chars not containing "?>" sequence between "?>" and "<?php"
        |                                  # or
        (?:\?>)(.+)                        # all chars after "?>"
    )/sx', 
    $yourcode,
    $matches
);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Everything you need will be in the first subgroup.
So the output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => THIS
,

    [1] => 
THIS


    [2] => 
THIS TOO


    [3] => AND 
THIS

)
```